# Docker: Unable to mount volume

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-cli

I am trying to mount the volume on my customized image.

```sh
docker run --rm -v models:/volumes/models <image-name>:latest
```

or

```sh
docker run --rm <image-name>:latest
```

Its throwing same error for both commands:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: invalid mount {Destination:[/volumes/models] Type:bind Source:/mnt/data/docker/volumes/beb849ff1498450a01aa69c9b143e51b15fc8d97316d318cfbd4ab72f60656de/_data Options:[rbind]}: mount destination [/volumes/models] not absolute: unknown.
```

My Docker version is :
Docker version 19.03.13, build 4484c46d9d

To crosscheck the image, I have mounted the same volume on another server and it worked

Am I missing something?

Comment: Can you edit the question to include the image's Dockerfile?  Without the `-v` option, is there something in `/volumes/models` already?